# pulsar-datadog configuration files into Data dog agent openmetrics.d directory not publishing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, datadog, apache-pulsar

Has anyone tried to implement the [pulsar-datadog](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog) configurations into their Kubernetes based Datadog agent. I've taken the steps to helm install the datadog agent to my kubernetes cluster and copied the provided [config .yaml files](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog/tree/master/configs) into the datadog trace agent directory at `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d`.

I've then imported the [JSON files](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog/tree/master/dashboards) under the dashboards directory into a datadog board. But nothing is populating.

I'm not sure I'm implementing the [tags](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog/blob/master/configs/bookie_conf.yaml#L30) correctly in the config files. Is there a way to confirm that, for instance, I have my bookie id correct?

## What I've done

#### Helm installed Datadog Agent into Kubernetes

```
➜ kubectl get pods -n datadog
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
datadog-cluster-agent-c65786576-8kqpb         1/1     Running   0          82m
datadog-gq9qr                                 3/3     Running   0          89m
datadog-kube-state-metrics-6fb56bf889-vt65l   1/1     Running   0          11h
datadog-v7k44                                 3/3     Running   0          90m
datadog-v9vht                                 3/3     Running   0          89m
```

#### Updated tags in configuration files to match pulsar pod names

For example:

```
➜ kubectl get pods -n pulsar 
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
...
event-platform-pulsar-1-sn-bookie-0              1/1     Running   0          9h
event-platform-pulsar-1-sn-bookie-1              1/1     Running   0          9h
event-platform-pulsar-1-sn-bookie-2              1/1     Running   0          9h
...
```

So in the [`bookie_conf.yaml`](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-datadog/blob/master/configs/bookie_conf.yaml#L30) I've added:

```
    tags:
      - pulsar-bookie: event-platform-pulsar-1-sn-bookie
```

#### Copied configuration files into trace agent at `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d`

```
root@datadog-gq9qr:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/openmetrics.d# ls
bookie_conf.yaml  conf.yaml.example  zookeeper_conf.yaml
broker_conf.yaml  proxy_conf.yaml
```

#### Restarted Datadog Agent to apply changes

`➜ kubectl rollout restart deployment datadog-cluster-agent -n datadog`

#### Imported dashboard JSON files into Datadog dashboard

[image]

Comment: You already pay a lot of money for the DD support, I would recommend using it. Manually copying files into the container sounds off to me. There is a helm value that you can use to provide yaml files for additional configuration, but I suspect all you really needed to do was enable prometheus metric collection on the agent.

Comment: I sent this to them too and if they have an answer I'll include it here. But I figured this felt like a general enough problem that the apache-pulsar community would benefit by recording ti somewhere.

I'll investigate a field that may be turned off to allow prometheus metric collection.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the [Pulsar helm chart `values.yaml`](https://github.com/streamnative/charts/blob/a3e2f2d94ce15638da91f4e7e8509f354c906adb/charts/pulsar/values.yaml#L1553) I found options for enabling datadog.

Updating my `values.yaml` with the following parameters and following the steps I originally outlined in my question, I was able to visualize the metrics in Datadog.

```
monitoring:
  # monitoring - prometheus
  prometheus: true
  # monitoring - datadog
  datadog: true

datadog:
  component: datadog
  namespace: pulsar
  components:
    zookeeper:
      enabled: true
      metrics: [
        "\"_*\""
      ]
    bookkeeper:
      enabled: true
      metrics: [
        "\"_*\""
      ]
    broker:
      enabled: true
      metrics: [
        "\"_*\""
      ]
    proxy:
      enabled: true
      metrics: [
        "\"_*\""
      ]
```